# .Net Remoting interface overloaded methods

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

We have a legacy app that uses .Net Remoting (we will soon convert it to use something better)

We have had an interface dll, shared between client and server, that looks like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ExampleInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<DataObject> InterfaceMethod(string strParam);
}
```

About two months ago, we needed a few more parameters so we created a `ParameterObject` and added a new overloaded function to support it; while leaving in the old function for older clients. So the interface now looks like:

```
[OperationContract]
List<DataObject> InterfaceMethod(string strParam);
[OperationContract]
List<DataObject> InterfaceMethod(ParameterObject parameter)
```

We have deployed the update and we are getting reports that when older clients try to call the method with the `string` parameter, an exception is thrown with the message `'Cannot resolve the invocation to the correct method'`. The server's exception stack trace is 100% remoting code.

I was able to reproduce in house and changing the newer method to a different name solved the issue, but this would mean we would have to update a lot of customers.

Is method overloading not possible in .Net Remoting? Are there any work-arounds to this?

**Note**: we have several working Remoting interfaces that overload methods, but they all have differing parameter counts, perhaps remoting cannot distinguish between two methods with the same name and same parameter count?

Comment: Is there any chance the method is getting called with a `null` value, or does it happen on any `string`?

Comment: A possible solution is to add the new method to `ExampleInterface2`, which inherits from `ExampleInterface`, to be used by new clients. But I'm hazy on how remoting actually resolves method calls. There *are* provisions for versioning, at least (involving strong-named assemblies).

Comment: Method overloading is not possible in WCF regardless of what binding you are using. Why do you  not use a new name for the new operation?

Comment: @JeroenMostert it is with any string

Comment: @CodingYoshi This is .Net remoting, not WCF. Though it is interesting that WCF doesn't allow overloads. We are considering changing the name, but that would force us to update a lot of customers so I was wondering if there were other alternatives. Sounds like .Net remoting might not support overloading either

Comment: @spectacularbob are you sure you are not using WCF with .Net remoting?

Comment: @CodingYoshi The communication is definitely .Net remoting, though I just tried to create a catch-all method with [OperationContract(Action="*")] and it didn't work. Perhaps we have thought we needed the `OperationContract` attributes for remoting and we didn't.

Comment: Yes, the attributes are unnecessary for .Net Remoting.

Comment: Also, Remoting supports overloaded methods.  What's the exact text of the error message?  I can't seem to find any references to the one you've given.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to the question.
Ran into the same error in a production environment that uses .NET remoting (no method overloading). Found out that one of the reference assemblies were of earlier version than the one used during development.

Comment: If it is not related to the question, why post this as an answer.

Comment: I didn’t affirmatively say it is unrelated. My error message is same but caused by a different issue than the original post. Worth looking into for someone facing the same error. Even with what is explained in the original post, the root cause of the issue could have been related to assembly mismatch and not related to method overloading as such.